# Vue, accessing data that's in a different v-for loop

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a table body in my Vue application where I've got one section of rows being built by a loop around a data object. I then have a separated section that is using a different data object, however, I need to compare a value from it to a value from the other loop in order to get conditional styling

I'm wondering if there is a way where I can send data from the `value` portion of the first for loop into a method call at the time of that v-for so that I can access it in the summary loop, if that makes sense

Here's the table:

```
  <tbody v-if="selected === 'Stores'">
  <tr v-for="(value, manager) in managerNumbers" :key="manager"> <!--Here is where I'm wondering if I can send value to a method call-->
    <td v-for="date in dates" :key="date" >
      <div v-for="(dataForDate, dateVal) in value.dates" :key="dateVal">
        <div v-if="dateVal == date ">
          @{{dataForDate.total_categories}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr><td colspan="10"></td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="10"></td></tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      Summary
    </th>
    <div v-for="store in activeStore" :key="store">
      <th :style="'background: ' + (value.qty > store.qty ? '#000' : '#fff')">@{{ store.stock_num }}</th>
    </div>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Are the indices of the `managerNumbers` and the indices of the `activeStore` the same at all points?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy yes they are

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I didn't even thing about adding that into the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use a computed method to create a lookup table between both `activeStore` and `managerNumbers` and loop over that.

```
get activeStoreAndManagerNumbers () {
 return managerNumbers.map((value, index) => {
    return {
      value, 
      store: activeStore[index] 
    }
  })
}
```

Now you can just loop over this array for both of your `v-for`:

`v-for="(obj, index) in activeStoreAndManagerNumbers"`

Now `obj.value.qty` and `obj.store.qty` are available in the same loop.